# Laptop shutdown during upgrade

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

My laptop battery died last night during an upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 and now, when I switch the laptop on, I get to the loading screen but no further. No obvious options appear on screen where I can boot into safe mode etc. It just freezes on the load screen. Anyone know what I can do to get it up n running again? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open recovery, with shift during boot. and repair packages.

Answer (score 1):

boot from your upgrade version CD and reinstall. but make sure you have your power supply plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't have the upgrade CD